# Re-prompt user if entered value is negative for multiple inputs

Tags: java, validation, for-loop, while-loop

I am asking the user to input 5 different numbers via a for loop. My problem is that I'm trying to validate said input to ensure negative numbers aren't entered, and to re-prompt the user to enter a valid integer if they enter a negative value. I have two separate versions that I tried.

(Code below: If I enter a positive value then the loop will stop. For example: By inputting 5 for the first iteration, it will ask the question one time only. It ignores iteration 2, 3, 4, 5.)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        while (day <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the amount of sales for day " + i);
            day = keyboard.nextInt();
            total += day; //accumulator
            sales.println("Day " + i + ": " + day);
        }
    }
```

(Code below: validation just doesn't work. User won't be re prompted, and the negative number will be stored.)

```
while (day <= 0) //don't accept negative numbers (less than 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the amount of sales for day " + i);
            day = keyboard.nextInt();
            total += day; //accumulator
            sales.println("Day " + i + ": " + day);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the while loop so that it will always ask the user to input the amount of sales
        unless the amount they entered is greater than or equal to 0. Ask if you have any questions.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the amount of sales for day " + i);
            day = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(day >= 0)
                break;
        }
            total += day; //accumulator
            sales.println("Day " + i + ": " + day);
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain this further? Trying to understand how placing the accumulator outside of the while loop still tracks the value inputted for day 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. I would think that it would only output one line like Day 1: 5.

Comment: The whole code is inside the for loop. The for loop here will execute 5 times, and each time, will follow this sequence. The while loop first executes till the input is valid, then the input is added to the total, and finally the input is outputted. That's all one iteration of the for loop.